# A match that gives me all the coincidences not just the first one

Tags: r, dataframe

good day, I had previously posted a question but it was too cumbersome and I overloaded it with data. Basically what I want to ask is that if there is any way to generate a dataset with  `match`  or some other function that gives me all the matches, even repeated values, when comparing two or more lists and if possible, that this function does not remove the " `NA` " of the result.
Example: I have this 2 frames

```
Frame 1                          Frame 2
GenIDModel  GenIDOrganisms       GenIDModel GenIDOrganism1
gen_pep01   hsa_pep01            gen_pep01  hsa_pep01
gen_pep01   hsa_pep02            gen_pep01  hsa_pep02
gen_pep01   hsa_pep03            gen_pep01  hsa_pep03
gen_pep03   hsa_pep11            gen_pep03  hsa_pep11
gen_pep05   hsa_pep20            gen_pep05  hsa_pep20
gen_pep02   rno_pep14           
gen_pep05   rno_pep22           
gen_pep05   rno_pep23           
gen_pep05   rno_pep25           
gen_pep01   dre_pep01           
gen_pep03   dre_pep08           
gen_pep08   dre_pep99           
gen_pep11   dre_pep99           
gen_pep02   rno_pep24           
gen_pep03   rno_pep35           
gen_pep05   rno_pep20           
gen_pep07   rno_pep27
```

When I use match

```
MatchFrame1vsFrame2 <- match(Frame1$GenIDModel, Frame2$GenIDModel)
```

I get this

```
MatchFrame1vsFrame2
# [1]  1  1  1  4  5 NA  5  5  5  1  4 NA NA NA  4  5 NA
```

And when I extract the names I get this

```
NamesMatchFrame1vsFrame2 <- Frame2$GenIDOrganism1[MatchFrame1vsFrame2]
NamesMatchFrame1vsFrame2
# [1] "hsa_pep01" "hsa_pep01" "hsa_pep01" "hsa_pep11" "hsa_pep20"
# [6] NA          "hsa_pep20" "hsa_pep20" "hsa_pep20" "hsa_pep01"
# [11] "hsa_pep11" NA          NA          NA          "hsa_pep11"
# [16] "hsa_pep20" NA
```

But what I actually want is this

```
# [1] "hsa_pep01" "hsa_pep02" "hsa_pep03" "hsa_pep11" "hsa_pep20"
# [6] NA          "rno_pep22" "rno_pep23" "rno_pep25" "dre_pep01"
# [11] "dre_pep08" NA          NA          NA          "rno_pep35"
# [16] "rno_pep20" NA
```

**Is there any function or series of functions that allows me to obtain something like this?**

Note:
I also tried with `%in%` but when I extract the names it doesn't give me all of them

```
inFrame1vsFrame2 <- Frame1$GenIDModel %in% Frame2$GenIDModel
inFrame1vsFrame2
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [11]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
NamesinFrame1vsFrame2 <- Frame2$GenIDOrganism1[inFrame1vsFrame2]
NamesinFrame1vsFrame2
# [1] "gen_pep01" "gen_pep01" "gen_pep01" "gen_pep03" "gen_pep05"
# [6] NA          NA          NA          NA          NA         
# [11] NA          NA
```

Thanks a lot for your time, have a great day!

Comment: I'm confused on the logic here. How would `rno_pep27` be returned in the expected result?

Comment: My bad, it should be `rno_pep20` thanks.

Comment: Hi @Luis T, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
ifelse(test = df1$GenIDModel %in% df2$GenIDModel, yes = df1$GenIDOrganisms, no = NA)

 [1] "hsa_pep01" "hsa_pep02" "hsa_pep03" "hsa_pep11" "hsa_pep20"
 [6] NA          "rno_pep22" "rno_pep23" "rno_pep25" "dre_pep01"
[11] "dre_pep08" NA          NA          NA          "rno_pep35"
[16] "rno_pep20" NA
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(GenIDModel = c("gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", 
"gen_pep03", "gen_pep05", "gen_pep02", "gen_pep05", "gen_pep05", 
"gen_pep05", "gen_pep01", "gen_pep03", "gen_pep08", "gen_pep11", 
"gen_pep02", "gen_pep03", "gen_pep05", "gen_pep07"), GenIDOrganisms = c("hsa_pep01", 
"hsa_pep02", "hsa_pep03", "hsa_pep11", "hsa_pep20", "rno_pep14", 
"rno_pep22", "rno_pep23", "rno_pep25", "dre_pep01", "dre_pep08", 
"dre_pep99", "dre_pep99", "rno_pep24", "rno_pep35", "rno_pep20", 
"rno_pep27")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))

df2 <- structure(list(GenIDModel = c("gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", 
"gen_pep03", "gen_pep05"), GenIDOrganism1 = c("hsa_pep01", "hsa_pep02", 
"hsa_pep03", "hsa_pep11", "hsa_pep20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about functions you use, but about the clear idea you've got about your data.

The logic behind your question, is to *replace* all the values in `df01$GeneIDOrganisms` where `df01$GenIDModel` and `df02$GenIDModel` *do not match*, with `NA`s.

To achieve this, you might want to consider standard `base::replace(x, list, values)` function. It replaces all values in `x`, with *indexes* given by `list`, with values given by `value`.

Which, in your particular case could be implemented this way:

```
replace(df01$GenIDOrganisms, ! df01$GenIDModel %in% df02$GenIDModel, NA)
```

---

Data:

```
df01 <- structure(list(GenIDModel = c("gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", 
"gen_pep03", "gen_pep05", "gen_pep02", "gen_pep05", "gen_pep05", 
"gen_pep05", "gen_pep01", "gen_pep03", "gen_pep08", "gen_pep11", 
"gen_pep02", "gen_pep03", "gen_pep05", "gen_pep07"), GenIDOrganisms = c("hsa_pep01", 
"hsa_pep02", "hsa_pep03", "hsa_pep11", "hsa_pep20", "rno_pep14", 
"rno_pep22", "rno_pep23", "rno_pep25", "dre_pep01", "dre_pep08", 
"dre_pep99", "dre_pep99", "rno_pep24", "rno_pep35", "rno_pep20", 
"rno_pep27")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))

df02 <- structure(list(GenIDModel = c("gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", "gen_pep01", 
"gen_pep03", "gen_pep05"), GenIDOrganism1 = c("hsa_pep01", "hsa_pep02", 
"hsa_pep03", "hsa_pep11", "hsa_pep20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

P.S.: Please read [how to make reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

P.P.S: Please read [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs109l/unrestricted/resources/google-style.html), it is extremely important to write *readable* code, even if you think it is not a priority for you right now.